# Coloring jQuery Slider sub-range

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I have a jQuery Slider that has a min-max associated with it.

```
$('#slide').slider({
    min: -127,
    max: 127,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var minrange = -20;
        var maxrange = 20;
        if ((ui.value >= minrange) && (ui.value <= maxrange)) {
            $('#current').text('current: ' + ui.value);
        }
        return ((ui.value >= minrange) && (ui.value <= maxrange));
    },
    value: 0,
});
```

The slider itself works fine.  My question is how can I color the minrange to maxrange with another color?

Something like:

```
========================-------[]---------------================================
```

Where the '-' is a different color from the '='